# Setting ng-Attributes with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I began coding angular since a short time

I got HTML with several divs and classes. Those classes I want to iterate and assign a tooltip to a div in that class. I don't want to put those angular attributes into the HTML as I need to dynamically produce it to evade to much code in the HTML.

For example using

```
button.setAttribute ("tooltip-placement", "bottom");
```

Angular ignores that and placement is the standard one: top.

How can I "persuade" angular to use my own handling of angular-attributes?

Thank you!

The following directive manipulating the DOM does not bring disired solutions:
altough it shows up in the DOM (inspecting it), angular ignores it. 
It should pop up a tooltip.

demoApp.directive('tooltipView', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

```
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.attr("tooltip-placement", scope.placement);
        element.attr("tooltip-html-unsafe", "testtooltip");
        element.attr("tooltip-trigger", "mouseover");
    }
};
```

})

Comment: Why can't you add these attributes in the editor? The sole point of Angular attributes is to minimize the amount of code in the view, as well as make the view easy to look at and determine what is happening.

Comment: I would like to add the attributes within a javascript-file not within an HTML-file as I want to dynamically determine attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to process changes of attributes to an element is by compiling it within the link function is as follows (example):

```
app.directive("tooltipView", function($compile) {

return {
    restrict: "AE",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {                 
        var tooltipContent = scope.tooltipHTML;     
        if (!element.attr('tooltip-html-unsafe')) { 
            element.attr("tooltip-html-unsafe", tooltipContent);
            $compile(element[0])(scope);
        }
    });    
   }    
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this all depends on when the tooltip gets generated. If the tooltip code is being run before your execute the `button.setAttribute(..)` code, you won't get the expected behaviour.

My first suggestion would be to use [angular-bootstra's tooltip wrapper](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip), and make use of the databinding angular provides to set the position.

Eg:

```
<... tooltip-placement="{{ scopePropertyIndicatingTooltipPlacement }}" ../>
```

With your controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.scopePropertyIndicatingTooltipPlacement = "right";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

What is that "scopePropertyIndicatingTooltipPlacement"? A data-binding or a property from the controller?

I cannot place any code within the view/HTML showing tooltips.

How can I generate a directive doing that for me?

Comment: @Pille yes, `scopePropertyIndicatingTooltipPlacement` is indeed a property from the controller. I'll update my answer to elaborate further..

Comment: And the code with "<...tooltip-placement=.../>
is an HTML?
My problem is i must generate attributes via pure JavaScript and persuade Angular to process it.

Comment: yes, that part is HTML - but it includes data bindings that are managed by angular (which allows you to use JavaScript to change them)

Comment: My problem is that I need to put attributes to a div to make a tooltip with a directive like shown in my edited question above.

Comment: Those added attributes are ignored by angular as they are not processed altough they show up in the DOM.